# How to modify the header to insert a long thesis title?

Tags: header-footer, thesis, toptesi

I'm writing my master thesis on Overleaf, using the template `toptesi` (https://it.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/italian-thesis-template-(toptesi)). I'm using the pattern:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,cucitura,oldstyle,autoretitolo,classica,greek]{toptesi}
```

Therefore, in the header I have on one page the thesis title and on the following page the chapter title.

The thesis title is too long, thus I'd like to understand if it is possible to use two rows on the header, in order to show all the title. I'd like to avoid using a shortened title.

Here's a screenshot of my problem:

[image: **enter image description here**]

Below an extract of my document (to be used with the files toptesi.sty, toptesi.cls, toptesi.cfg, topfront.sty, topcoman.sty available at https://it.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/italian-thesis-template-(toptesi)):

```
\let\oldbreve\breve
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,cucitura,oldstyle,autoretitolo,classica,greek]{toptesi}
\usepackage[or]{teubner}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
    pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
    bookmarksopen,
    pdfstartview={FitH},
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue},
    citecolor={red},
    urlcolor={blue}
  }

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}
%-----------------------------------------%
\ateneo{University}
\nomeateneo{}
\FacoltaDi{}
\titolo{very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title }
\sottotitolo{subtitle}
\corsodilaurea{Engineering}
\candidato{Candidate Name}
\relatore{prof.\ bla bla}
\tutoreaziendale{bla bla}
\sedutadilaurea{\textsc{Academic~Year} 2222}
%\logosede{} 
%------------------------------%
\newtheorem{osservazione}{Remark}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{notoccite} 
\let\breve\oldbreve
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{rotating}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

% Nomenclature:
\usepackage[intoc, english]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Acronyms}

\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\if#1A%
 \formattitle{Abbreviation}%
\else
  \if#1S%
    \formattitle[0pt]{Symbols}%
  \else
    \if#1P%
      \formattitle{Subscripts}%
    \else
      \if#1N
        \formattitle{Notation}
      \else
        \GenericError{\string\nomgroup}{The argument can be only A, S, N or P}{}{}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
\fi}
\newcommand{\formattitle}[2][15pt]{\vspace{#1}\item[\sffamily #2]}%o 10pt
\makenomenclature
%------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}\errorcontextlines=9
\english
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \iflanguage{english}{%
    \retrofrontespizio{This work is subject to the Creative Commons Licence}
    \DottoratoIn{PhD Course in\space}
    \CorsoDiLaureaIn{Master degree course in\space}
    \NomeMonografia{Bachelor Degree Thesis}
    \TesiDiLaurea{Master Degree Thesis}
    \NomeDissertazione{PhD Dissertation}
    \InName{in}
    \CandidateName{Candidate:}
    \AdvisorName{Supervisor}
    \TutorName{Tutor}
    \NomeTutoreAziendale{Internship Tutor:}
    \CycleName{cycle}
    \NomePrimoTomo{First volume}
    \NomeSecondoTomo{Second Volume}
    \NomeTerzoTomo{Third Volume}
    \NomeQuartoTomo{Fourth Volume}
    }{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\expandafter\ifx\csname StileTrieste\endcsname\relax
    \frontespizio
\else
    \paginavuota
    \begin{dedica}
        ...
        \textdagger\ ....
    \end{dedica}
    \tomo
\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\sommario

summary
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ringraziamenti

bla bla
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tablespagetrue\figurespagetrue 
\begingroup\let\mainmatter\relax
\printnomenclature
\endgroup
\indici

\expandafter\ifx\csname StileTrieste\endcsname\relax
\else
    \begin{citazioni}
        \textit{testo testo testo\\testo testo testo}

        [\textsc{bla bla}, test]

        \textgreek{>all'a p'anta <o k'eraunos d'' >oiak'izei}

        [Eraclito, fr.\ D-K 134]
    \end{citazioni}

\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mainmatter
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
.....................
The contents...
\clearpage
The contents...
\clearpage
The contents...
\clearpage
The contents...
\chapter{Test}
The contents... The contents... The contents... The contents...
The contents...
The contents...The contents... The contents...

The contents... The contents...
The contents... The contents... The contents... The contents...
The contents...
The contents...The contents... The contents...
\clearpage
The contents... The contents...The contents... The contents... The contents... The contents...
The contents...
The contents...The contents... The contents...

The contents... The contents...The contents... The contents...The contents... The contents... The contents... The contents...
The contents...
The contents...The contents... The contents...

The contents... The contents...
\clearpage
The contents...

The contents... The contents...
\clearpage
The contents...
\clearpage
The contents...

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{gal} G.~Galilei, {\em Nuovi studii sugli astri medicei}, Manunzio,
        Venetia, 1612.
\end{thebibliography}
%----------------- Appendices-------------------%
\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Some Appendix}
The contents...

\end{appendices}

\nomenclature[S]{a}{prova}
\nomenclature[P]{b}{prova}
\nomenclature[N]{c}{prova}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick idea: use a short title in the header instead. People won't read that title in the header anyways

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I made an example to be used with the files at the indicated link.

Comment: I tried to compile your code, unfortunately I get errors about `\ateneo` etc. being undefined. Does it compile for you?

Comment: Using it with all 5 files mentioned, it works correctly; the only errors are related to the length of the title (I'm using Overleaf).

Comment: @MiKaEl - I am also unable to compile your code without running into an errror message related to the `\ateneo` macro.

Comment: If I compile the script using Overleaf, including the aforementioned files into the working environment (**toptesi.sty, toptesi.cls, toptesi.cfg, topfront.sty, topcoman.sty**), it doesn't return errors related to `\ateneo`. If you open [link](https://it.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/italian-thesis-template-(toptesi)) you can find them; if you do not include these 5 files in the working space, the code returns that error. All this using Overleaf.